# Remove html extenstion using htacces file

Tags: html, .htaccess

It's seems that I can't figure out what to do in order to get rid of the .html extention. The guys from where I have the hosting plan, said that I have to place the htacces rules in the  web.confing file.

In that file I have those lines:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <configuration>
>     <system.webServer>
>     <defaultDocument>
>       <files>
>         <remove value="index.php" />
>         <add value="index.php" />
>         <add value="_deploy.php" />
>      </files>
>     </defaultDocument>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

And since now, I have used this htacces file and worked just fine, but at this host provider, doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Can someone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: .htaccess files have never worked since mohommed invented them.

Comment: something like 600 AD.  look for something more old school?

Answer (score 0):

To remove `.html` using web.config you can use the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="removehtml" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You will then be able to call your files without the extensions. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Hey @Lag 

The files are on a ISS Server, they told me. I think this is not gonna work